# ...the drawers roll open midair

Tags: parts-of-speech

> We just totally forget about Tyler's whole murder-suicide thing while we watch another file cabinet slip out the side of the building and the drawers roll open midair, reams of white paper caught in the updraft and carried off on the wind.

Source: Chuck Palahniuk, *Fight Club*

Just cannot get the meaning of this part, "the drawers roll open midair".
I have problem with understanding what role played  the word, "open" here?
Is it phrasal verb, "roll open" or open should be connected with "midair"?

Comment: Here, "open" is indeed modifying "roll". As in the phrasal verb "open up", but in this case "open" is an adjective (or ad adverb). As the cabinet falls out of the building, it tumbles, gravity and momentum causing its drawers to roll out on their bearings, before the cabinet even hits the ground, i.e. in mid-air. I should note, however, that this question should probably been asked on our sister site, [ELL.se].

Comment: @Dirty Hippy, if this is a quote from someone else (book?  TV show?), please cite the source.